# How can I add link with var in bootstrap popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, tooltip

I try use this one

Html

```
<div class="company-logo">
    <a class="popup" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Download den Mazda Case (.pdf)">
        <img src="img/logo/mazda.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var pop_description = $(this).attr("data-content");
    var pop_link = $(this).attr("href");
    var pop_content = '<a href="' + pop_link + '">' + pop_description + '</a>';


    $('.popup').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        content: pop_description
    });

});
```

But it's wrong, and I have undefined. I want to add link into popover content

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be?

Comment: added more description

Comment: What do you mean by **"and I have undefined"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom popover called 'my-popover'

HTML

```
<div class="company-logo">
    <a class="popup" href="#" data-toggle="my-popover" data-content="Download den Mazda Case (.pdf)">
        <img src="img/logo/mazda.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="my-popover"]').popover({
        'placement': 'top',
        'template':'<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div><a href="' + pop_link + '"><div class="popover-content"></div></a></div></div>',
        'html': 'true'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this ?

```
$(function () {
    var pop_description = $(this).attr("data-content");
    var pop_link = $(this).attr('href','http://example.com');
    var pop_content = '<a href="' + pop_link + '">' + pop_description + '</a>';
alert(pop_content);

    $('.popup').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
       // content: pop_description
    });

});
```

I hope i am getting you what you want to do ?

Comment: Nope. I just need to add link into the content of bootstrap popover